# Dynamic content in JavaScript in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

If got this full screen background slider (Vegas) on a site thats using Wordpress. Now the slider is called using this script:

```
<script>
        $("body").vegas({
            delay: 7000,
            timer: false,
            shuffle: true,
            transition: 'fade',
            transitionDuration: 2000,
            slides: [
                { src: "photo01.jpg" },
                { src: "photo02.jpg" },
                { src: "photo03.jpg" },
                { src: "photo04.jpg" }
            ],

            overlay: '01.png'
        });
        </script>
```

Within Wordpress it is possible to make a loop which "loops" the content that is in that file. What I would like to do is something like this:

```
....   
    slides: [
                    <?php get_template_part('loop-backgrounds'); ?>
                    { src: "some-file-to-stop-the-backgrounds.jpg" }
                ],
....
```

The `loop-backgrounds` would look something like this:

```
    <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'backgrounds', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby'=>'id', 'order' => 'ASC') );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

        { src: <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail();
            } ;?> },

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

This `some-file-to-stop-the-backgrounds.jpg` doesn't have a `,` at the end so it wouldn't break the code (i think). Is this at all possible?

Comment: Why do think something is not possible? Where did you face problems implementing this? Can you please elaborate, what the question is? (Besides “Is this at all possible?”; Answer: everything is possible)

Comment: Well... I read somewhere you cant put php inside javascript. And the question is what would be the right way to get this done? Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using WordPress i'd just find a full width background slider plugin that does what you need out of the box. I use this [full width background slider](https://wordpress.org/plugins/background-slider-master/) on a few of my websites and it works great and loads fast.

Give it a shot, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your awnser but i got it working. Just added some php and it worked. I thought it wasn't possible but it worked.